# Ansible to many ssh login

Tags: ssh, ansible

We have been using ansible for deployment. When I login to server type `last` command it shows too many login any idea why there are so many login in?

```
deployer pts/0        ip-10-0-0-xxx.ap Tue Oct  3 08:54 - 08:54  (00:00)    
deployer pts/0        ip-10-0-0-xxx.ap Tue Oct  3 08:54 - 08:54  (00:00)    
deployer pts/0        ip-10-0-0-xxx.ap Tue Oct  3 08:54 - 08:54  (00:00)    
deployer pts/0        ip-10-0-0-xxx.ap Tue Oct  3 08:54 - 08:54  (00:00)    
deployer pts/0        ip-10-0-0-xxx.ap Tue Oct  3 08:54 - 08:54  (00:00)    
deployer pts/0        ip-10-0-0-xxx.ap Tue Oct  3 08:54 - 08:54  (00:00)    
deployer pts/0        ip-10-0-0-xxx.ap Tue Oct  3 08:54 - 08:54  (00:00)    
deployer pts/0        ip-10-0-0-xxx.ap Tue Oct  3 08:54 - 08:54  (00:00)    
deployer pts/0        ip-10-0-0-xxx.ap Tue Oct  3 08:54 - 08:54  (00:00)    
deployer pts/0        ip-10-0-0-xxx.ap Tue Oct  3 08:54 - 08:54  (00:00)    
deployer pts/0        ip-10-0-0-xxx.ap Tue Oct  3 08:54 - 08:54  (00:00)    
deployer pts/0        ip-10-0-0-xxx.ap Tue Oct  3 08:54 - 08:54  (00:00)    
deployer pts/0        ip-10-0-0-xxx.ap Tue Oct  3 08:54 - 08:54  (00:00)    
deployer pts/0        ip-10-0-0-xxx.ap Tue Oct  3 08:54 - 08:54  (00:00)    
deployer pts/0        ip-10-0-0-xxx.ap Tue Oct  3 08:54 - 08:54  (00:00)    
deployer pts/0        ip-10-0-0-xxx.ap Tue Oct  3 08:54 - 08:54  (00:00)    
deployer pts/0        ip-10-0-0-xxx.ap Tue Oct  3 08:54 - 08:54  (00:00)    
deployer pts/0        ip-10-0-0-xxx.ap Tue Oct  3 08:54 - 08:54  (00:00)    
deployer pts/0        ip-10-0-0-xxx.ap Tue Oct  3 08:54 - 08:54  (00:00)    
deployer pts/0        ip-10-0-0-xxx.ap Tue Oct  3 08:54 - 08:54  (00:00)    
deployer pts/0        ip-10-0-0-xxx.ap Tue Oct  3 08:54 - 08:54  (00:00)    
deployer pts/0        ip-10-0-0-xxx.ap Tue Oct  3 08:54 - 08:54  (00:00)    
deployer pts/0        ip-10-0-0-xxx.ap Tue Oct  3 08:54 - 08:54  (00:00)    
deployer pts/0        ip-10-0-0-xxx.ap Tue Oct  3 08:54 - 08:54  (00:00)    
deployer pts/0        ip-10-0-0-xxx.ap Tue Oct  3 08:54 - 08:54  (00:00)    
deployer pts/0        ip-10-0-0-xxx.ap Tue Oct  3 08:54 - 08:54  (00:00)    
deployer pts/0        ip-10-0-0-xxx.ap Tue Oct  3 08:54 - 08:54  (00:00)    
deployer pts/0        ip-10-0-0-xxx.ap Tue Oct  3 08:54 - 08:54  (00:00)    
deployer pts/0        ip-10-0-0-xxx.ap Tue Oct  3 08:54 - 08:54  (00:00)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your configuration Ansible can make up to 5 distinct SSH connections for each task in the playbook.

Make sure you have enabled control sockets and pipelining mode to reduce number of connections and increase speed.
See [this article](https://www.ansible.com/blog/ansible-performance-tuning) (section *OpenSSH connection tips*) for details.

Comment: Thank you  @Konstantin. I will go through the article.